# Android connect to personal web server

Tags: android, webserver, xampp

I have set up my own personal web server using xampp. I have also used www.noip.com to have my own domain. The web server is up and can be accessed from any browser. My goal is for an android app to connect to the personal web server and query the data from the MySql part of xampp. How will i do this in the android part?

Answer (score 0):

Can create a webservice and connect, or do a http call. Or if you are using sql server, you can query directly from your device as well.

To query directly to sql server:

```
String connectionstring = serverName + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
connectionstring = connectionstring + ";instance=" + instance;
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(3000);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" +     connectionstring, username, password);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

Comment: How can you query directly from your device?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make an API, and access it using a http request.

http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/
http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

its not that hard, everyone is doing it now a days.

you can also use something like parse.com, if you are not too good with server side coding

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly connect with MySql.... for achieving this purpose you can use [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) format for receive and send data.... You also can save data in MySql database with using web languages by passing parameters...

[JSON Tutorial Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)